# Basic Vue to do list: the added list item does not show

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a simple todo list in Vue using a tutorial but the new items do not appear. What did I do wrong? Is there something missing?

```
<template>
      <div id="app">
        <div class="container">
          <h1>To Do List</h1>
          <input
            class="input"
            v-modell="newToDo"
            />
            <button class="add-button" v-on:click="add()">Add</button>
            <ul style="List-style-type: none;">
              <li v-for="(todo,i) in existingToDo">
                <span> 
                {{ i + 1 }}: {{todo.text}}
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'app',
      data () {
        return {
          newToDo:``,
          existingToDo:[
            {text: `Get Groceries`, id:0},
            {text: `Run Errands`, id:1},
            {text: `Do Sports`, id:3}
          ]
        }
      },
      methods:{
        add(){
          this.existingToDo.push({
            text: this.newToDo,
            id: new Date().valueOf()
          }),
          this.newToDo=``
        },
        
      }
    }
    
    </script>
    
    <style>
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi there. If the minimum length filter says you need to write a longer description, please don't copy+paste what you have. Readers generally regard that as vandalism. Stack Overflow is a curated Q&A, not too dissimilar to documentation or a wiki. Posts that are readable and understandable is a key requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to fix typo. (modell) double `l` letter.
2. I think you have to use `uuid` for getting `id`.

   import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

   ```
    methods: {
            add(event){
                event.preventDefault();



    this.existingToDo.push= {
                    id: uuidv4(),
                    text: this.newTodo
                }



    this.$emit("add-todo-event", existingToDo);
            this.newTodo= '';
        }
    }
   ```

maybe try to do it.

Comment: IDs do not need to be UUIDs. They just need to be unique in the context of the `v-for` model.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's the typo in your `<input>`: Try using `v-model` instead of `v-modell`. As of now, there is no new `newToDo` data property because the link to your input field is broken.

Comment: Adding comment to my answer since I can't to the accepted one: I don't think the answer is completely correct. First, you *can* of course use uuids to identify your ToDos. No one (I guess neither does your tutorial) says you have to. I would be completely fine to use the index of the element in your array. Sidenote: Vue expects you to also bind a `:key` to an element that uses `v-for`. Look out for warnings in your browser's dev console. Second, I don't see why you would use the `$emit` event in your example since everything is in a single Vue component.